# Check first firebase login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to check the login with Firebase Authentication

Here is my code

```
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {

                String userEmail = user.getEmail();
                String id = user.getProviderId();
                String username = user.getDisplayName();
                // User is signed in
                onSignedInInitialize(id, username, userEmail);
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                onSignedOutCleanup();
                startActivityForResult(
                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false, true)
                                .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                                .build(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };
    OnCompleteListener<AuthResult> completeListener = new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                boolean isNew = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
                Log.d("MyTAG", "onComplete: " + (isNew ? "new user" : "old user"));
            }
        }
    };
```

i checked a few posts about it, it says to add a onCompleteListener to a task, but where I have to create the task?

Comment: Download this example and use you can get an Idea https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth